# How to improve std::set_intersection performance in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, set, hashtable

During experimenting with std::set in C++ and set() in Python I faced performance issue that I can't explain. Set intersection in C++ at least 3 times slower than in Python.

So could anybody point me at optimization that could be done to C++ code and/or explain how Python do this so much faster?

I expect that both of them use similar algorithm with O(n) complexity while set is ordered. But probably Python do some optimizations so it reach smaller coefficient.

set_bench.cc

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

void elapsed(std::function<void()> f, const std::string& s)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << s << " " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void fill_set(std::set<T>& s, T start, T end, T step)
{
    for (T i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        s.emplace(i);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void intersect(const std::set<T>& s1, const std::set<T>& s2, std::set<T>& result)
{
    std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                            s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                            std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int64_t> s1;
    std::set<int64_t> s2;
    std::set<int64_t> s3;

    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), 8, 1000*1000*100, 13), "fill s1 took");
    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s2), 0, 1000*1000*100, 7), "fill s2 took");

    std::cout << "s1 length = " << s1.size() << ", s2 length = " << s2.size() << std::endl;

    elapsed(std::bind(intersect<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), std::ref(s2), std::ref(s3)), "intersect s1 and s2 took");

    std::cout << "s3 length = " << s3.size() << std::endl;

    // sleep to let check memory consumption
    // while (true) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

set_bench.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time

def elapsed(f, s):
    start = time.monotonic()
    f()
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - start
    print(f'{s} {elapsed} seconds')

def fill_set(s, start, end, step=1):
    for i in range(start, end, step):
        s.add(i)

def intersect(s1, s2, result):
    result.update(s1 & s2)

s1 = set()
s2 = set()

elapsed(lambda : fill_set(s1, 8, 1000*1000*100, 13), 'fill s1 took')
elapsed(lambda : fill_set(s2, 0, 1000*1000*100, 7), 'fill s2 took')

print(f's1 length = {len(s1)}, s2 length = {len(s2)}')


s3 = set()

elapsed(lambda: intersect(s1, s2, s3), 'intersect s1 and s2 took')

print(f's3 length = {len(s3)}')

# sleep to let check memory consumption
# while True: time.sleep(1)
```

Here is results of running this programs in next environment:

- clang version 7.0.1
- gcc 8.2.0
- Python 3.7.2
- i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz

```
$ clang -lstdc++ -O0 set_bench.cc -o set_bench && ./set_bench
fill s1 took 5.38646 seconds
fill s2 took 10.5762 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 1.48387 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

```
$ clang -lstdc++ -O1 set_bench.cc -o set_bench && ./set_bench
fill s1 took 3.31435 seconds
fill s2 took 6.41415 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 1.01276 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

```
$ clang -lstdc++ -O2 set_bench.cc -o set_bench && ./set_bench
fill s1 took 1.90269 seconds
fill s2 took 3.85651 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.512727 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

```
$ clang -lstdc++ -O3 set_bench.cc -o set_bench && ./set_bench
fill s1 took 1.92473 seconds
fill s2 took 3.72621 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.523683 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

```
$ gcc -lstdc++ -O3 set_bench.cc -o set_bench && time ./set_bench
fill s1 took 1.72481 seconds
fill s2 took 3.3846 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.516702 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

```
$ python3.7 ./set_bench.py 
fill s1 took 0.9404696229612455 seconds
fill s2 took 1.082577683031559 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.17995300807524472 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

As you can see results are equal so I assume both programs do the same calculations.

By the way - RSS for C++ program is 1084896 kB and for Python - 1590400 kB.

Comment: Chances are you can't improve the performance of the C++ Standard Library algorithm. It's already optimized.

Comment: Have you tried using unordered_set? You are comparing the performance of a C++ set, which is ordered, with a python set, which is not.

Comment: @harmic unordered set is not ordered. set_intersection requires ordered ranges

Comment: Concerning intersection of unordered sets, there once was a question: [SO: unordered set intersection in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47901339/7478597). (I googled out of curiosity and found it worth to mention.)

Comment: Using sorted vector seems to be far more efficient than your std::set implementation. So maybe you can use a kind of sorted_iterator_inserter :)

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm a bit confused by your comment, since your own answer seems to be doing exactly what I am suggestion?

Comment: @harmic I realised I could rewrite set_intersect. Having said that, it seems like the std::unordered_set is lacking some interface. intersect etc really should be a feature.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @rustyx Debian testing

Comment: You could also try using *sorted vectors* instead of `std::set`

Answer (score 13):

There are two questions in this post:

> Q: *How to improve `std::set_intersection` performance in C++?*

Use sorted `std::vector`s instead of sets, that's much more cache-friendly. Since the intersection is done sequentially in a single pass, it will be as fast as it can get.
On my system I got a **0.04 s** run time.
Stop here if this is all you needed.

> Q: *... how [does] Python do this so much faster?*

Or in other words "***why is Python's set faster than the C++ set?***". I'll focus on this question for the rest of my post.

First of all, a Python's `set` is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and `std::set` is a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). So use `std::unordered_set` to compare apples to apples (we reject a binary tree at this point based on its O(*logN*) lookup complexity).

Note also that `std::set_intersection` is simply a [two-pointer algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/); it iterates over two *sorted* sets, keeping only matching values.
Apart from it's name, there is nothing in common with Python's [`set_intersection`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1238), which by itself is just a simple loop:

- Iterate over the smaller hashtable
- For each element, if it exists in the other hashtable, add it to the result

So we can't use `std::set_intersection` on unsorted data, and need to implement the loop:

```
    for (auto& v : set1) {
        if (set2.find(v) != set2.end()) {
            result.insert(v);
        }
    }
```

Nothing fancy here. Unfortunately though a straightforward application of this algorithm on `std::unordered_set` is ***still slower*** by a factor of 3. *How can that be?*

1. We observe that the input data set is > 100MB in size. That won't fit in 8MB the cache of an i7-7700, which means the more work you can fit within the boundaries of 8MB, the faster your program will perform.
2. Python uses a special form of ["dense hash table"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html) similar to that of [PHP hash table](https://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html) (generally a class of [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) hash tables), whereas the C++ `std::unordered_set` is typically a naïve, or *vector-of-lists*, hash table. A dense structure is much more cache-friendly, and thus faster. For implementation details see [dictobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c) and [setobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c).
3. The built-in C++ `std::hash<long>` is too complex for the already unique input data set you're generating. Python on the other hand uses an identity (no-op) hashing function for integers up to 2<sup>30</sup> (see [`long_hash`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6d43f6f081023b680d9db4542d19b9e382149f0a/Objects/longobject.c#L3031)). Collisions are amortised by the LCG built into their hashtable implementation. You can't match that with C++ standard library features; an identity hash here will unfortunately again result in a too sparse hashtable.
4. Python uses a custom memory allocator [pymalloc](https://www.evanjones.ca/memoryallocator/), which is similar to [jemalloc](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919) and optimized for data locality. It generally outperform the built-in Linux tcmalloc, which is what a C++ program would normally use.

With that knowledge we can contrive a similarly performing C++ version, to demonstrate the technical feasibility:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void elapsed(std::function<void()> f, const std::string& s)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f();
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << s << " " << (end - start) / 1.0s << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
struct myhash {
    size_t operator()(T x) const {
        return x / 5; // cheating to improve data locality
    }
};

template <typename T>
using myset = std::unordered_set<T, myhash<T>>;

template <typename T>
void fill_set(myset<T>& s, T start, T end, T step)
{
    s.reserve((end - start) / step + 1);
    for (T i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        s.emplace(i);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void intersect(const myset<T>& s1, const myset<T>& s2, myset<T>& result)
{
    result.reserve(s1.size() / 4); // cheating to compete with a better memory allocator
    for (auto& v : s1)
    {
        if (s2.find(v) != s2.end())
            result.insert(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    myset<int64_t> s1;
    myset<int64_t> s2;
    myset<int64_t> s3;

    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), 8, 1000 * 1000 * 100, 13), "fill s1 took");
    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s2), 0, 1000 * 1000 * 100, 7), "fill s2 took");

    std::cout << "s1 length = " << s1.size() << ", s2 length = " << s2.size() << std::endl;

    elapsed(std::bind(intersect<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), std::ref(s2), std::ref(s3)), "intersect s1 and s2 took");

    std::cout << "s3 length = " << s3.size() << std::endl;
}
```

With this code I got 0.28 s run times in both C++ and Python versions.

Now if we want to *beat* Python's set performance, we can remove all cheats and use Google's [`dense_hash_set`](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash), which implements [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) with quadratic probing, as a drop-in replacement (just need to call `set_empty_object(0)`).

With `google::dense_hash_set` and a no-op hashing function, we get:

```
fill s1 took 0.321397 seconds
fill s2 took 0.529518 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285714
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.0974416 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

Or 2.8 times faster than Python, while keeping the hash set functionality!

---

P.S. One would think - why does the C++ standard library implement such a slow hash table?
The no-free-lunch theorem also applies here: a probing-based solution is not *always* fast; being an opportunistic solution, it sometimes suffers from "clumping" (endlessly probing into occupied space).
And when that happens, performance drop exponentially.
The idea behind the standard library implementation was to guarantee predictable performance for all possible inputs. Unfortunately though the caching effect on modern hardware is too great to be neglected, as Chandler Carruth explains in [his talk](https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=2805).

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are not comparing like with like.

Python sets are unordered (hash) sets. `std::set<>` is an ordered set (a binary tree).

From the python docs:

> 5.4. Sets
>   Python also includes a data type for sets. **A set is an unordered collection** with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference.

refactoring to compare like with like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>

void elapsed(std::function<void()> f, const std::string& s)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << s << " " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void fill_set(std::unordered_set<T>& s, T start, T end, T step)
{
    for (T i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        s.emplace(i);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void intersect(const std::unordered_set<T>& s1, const std::unordered_set<T>& s2, std::unordered_set<T>& result)
{
    auto ordered_refs = [&]()
    {
        if (s1.size() <= s2.size())
            return std::tie(s1, s2);
        else
            return std::tie(s2, s1);
    };

    auto lr = ordered_refs();
    auto& l = std::get<0>(lr);
    auto& r = std::get<1>(lr);
    result.reserve(l.size());

    for (auto& v : l)
    {
        if (auto i = r.find(v) ; i != r.end())
            result.insert(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int64_t> s1;
    std::unordered_set<int64_t> s2;
    std::unordered_set<int64_t> s3;

    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), 8, 1000*1000*100, 13), "fill s1 took");
    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s2), 0, 1000*1000*100, 7), "fill s2 took");

    std::cout << "s1 length = " << s1.size() << ", s2 length = " << s2.size() << std::endl;

    elapsed(std::bind(intersect<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), std::ref(s2), std::ref(s3)), "intersect s1 and s2 took");

    std::cout << "s3 length = " << s3.size() << std::endl;

    // sleep to let check memory consumption
    // while (true) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

performance will depend on your kit.

I suspect you can increase performance vastly with a custom allocator. The default one is thread-safe, etc.

Having said this, on my machine I only saw a 20% speedup with the unordered version. I'd hazard a guess that the python intersect code has been hand-optimised.

For reference, python source code is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c

Comment: Like the `std::tie` for optionally swapping. can be terser with c++17 structured bindings, also don't need the named lambda and just immediately invoke it: `auto [l, r] = [&]() {
    if (s1.size() <= s2.size()) return std::tie(s1, s2);
    return std::tie(s2, s1);
  }();`

Answer (score 3):

Using sorted `vector` will far out-perform `set` on this benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

void elapsed(std::function<void()> f, const std::string& s)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << s << " " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void fill_set(std::vector<T>& s, T start, T end, T step)
{
    for (T i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        s.emplace_back(i);
    }
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
}

template <typename T>
void intersect(const std::vector<T>& s1, const std::vector<T>& s2, std::vector<T>& result)
{
    std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                            s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                            std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int64_t> s1;
    std::vector<int64_t> s2;
    std::vector<int64_t> s3;

    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), 8, 1000*1000*100, 13), "fill s1 took");
    elapsed(std::bind(fill_set<int64_t>, std::ref(s2), 0, 1000*1000*100, 7), "fill s2 took");

    std::cout << "s1 length = " << s1.size() << ", s2 length = " << s2.size() << std::endl;

    elapsed(std::bind(intersect<int64_t>, std::ref(s1), std::ref(s2), std::ref(s3)), "intersect s1 and s2 took");

    std::cout << "s3 length = " << s3.size() << std::endl;

    // sleep to let check memory consumption
    // while (true) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

For me (clang/libc++ -O3) this took the results from:

```
fill s1 took 2.01944 seconds
fill s2 took 3.98959 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 1.55453 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

to:

```
fill s1 took 0.143026 seconds
fill s2 took 0.20209 seconds
s1 length = 7692308, s2 length = 14285715
intersect s1 and s2 took 0.0548819 seconds
s3 length = 1098901
```

The reason for this performance difference is far fewer allocations in the `vector` version.

Comment: The speedup here is surprising to me. For me, gcc8.2 and apple clang (O3, march=native) only managed to reduce the time to 0.378 compared to python's 0.26

Comment: My best guess is this is due to the differences in `std::sort` between gcc's libstdc++ and clang's libc++.  The latter is very fast when given a range that is already sorted, which is so in this case.

Comment: mea culpa - forgot to change the container type. Better now: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/959ab8d12c397777

Comment: This just exploits the regularity in the benchmark. I doubt OP's actual input is sorted.

Comment: It is the `vector` that is responsible for most of the performance increase:  far fewer allocations, better cache behavior.  An unsorted input will increase the fill time, but not to the level of the `set` fill time.  An unsorted input will have no impact at all on the intersect time.